# Convert code from ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a classic ASP application where several shared functions are in a single file "functions.asp" which is included in other pages through the directive `<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->` when some of such functions are needed.

I searched for a while and found that most of the suggestions about converting the include directive in old ASP to ASP.NET point to the creation of user controls.

When code is full ASP code I understand how to do it but I have many functions where ASP code is mixed with HTML such as

```
<% function add(x, y)
if x > y then %>
<table><tr><td>Number <%=x%> is greater than <%= y %> </td></tr></table>
<% else %>
<table><tr><td>Number <%=y%> is greater than <%= x %></td></tr></table>
<% end if %>
<% end function %>
```

Ideally I'd like to take the function as is from classic ASP to ASP.NET because I need to have the old application running under ASP.NET. Any tip on the most efficient way to convert this code to ASP.NET without using Response.Write for the HTML part?

Comment: You can just create a static class with static methods on it if you wanted... Really though you just need to go and find out how ASP.NET works... This question makes me think that you need to just look into some more basic tutorials.

Comment: @halfer I'm dealing with same problem right now. Did you find a good way to do what you were after in the meantime?

Comment: I haven't deal with this problem - the only involvement I have with this question is editing it.